# Assigning separate logger to each class instance in Python as the instance's attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am writing a library for simulating a certain distributed process, where we distinguish between one central entity and corresponding decentralised clients. Each client is represented as an instance of a general class `client` that serves as a boilerplate for it. During the simulation, each instance is independently kept in memory and has associated attributes that store its simulation data. **I am trying to implement how to differentiate between different loggers for the central entity and each corresponding instance of a client class.**

For now, my workaround is as follows: the *Central Entity* and *Client Class* are kept in different modules. On the top of each module, I import different loggers from my custom factory class to initialize at the beginning of each module.

```
class Loggers:
    @staticmethod
    def central_logger():
        central_logger = logging.getLogger("central_logger")
        central_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        central_logger.addHandler(ch)
        central_logger.propagate = False
        return central_logger
    @staticmethod
    def client_logger():
        # Creating a head logger for the nodes
        client_logger = logging.getLogger("node_logger")
        client_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        zh = logging.StreamHandler()
        zh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        zh.setFormatter(formatter)
        client_logger.addHandler(zh)
        client_logger.propagate = False
        return client_logger
```

This way, I am able to differentiate between **central logger** and **client_logger**. However, I tried to initialize an instance of the logger as an attribute of a class. For example:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.logger = Loggers.client_logger(*here we could pass arguments to individualise the logger for a particular client*)
```

This, however - does not return a satisfactory result, as each client is resetting to a default general logger by the end.

Is there a smart way to initialize a logger as an attribute of a class in the scenario described above?

Comment: You say that "here we could pass arguments to individualise the logger for a particular client". But you cannot. Because there can only be one logger named "node_logger". Every time one of those objects initialises, you're re-setting the node_logger. And it will be the same for every client.

Comment: If you need to dynamically create loggers, then you need to have an id for each client object, and they need to pass that id to client_logger, and you must do logging.getLogger(id)

Comment: Loggers are globally available. Once you've set up "node_logger" you don't need to return it. You set it up. Once it's created, you fetch it elsewhere by calling logging.getLogger again with the same name.

Comment: Take a look at the `logging.config` module. There are already ways to configure loggers using configuration files and `dict`s instead of implementing your own static methods or functions.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I need to clarify a few things that I've seen during the tests. Adding a return statement was the only way to make it work that I've figured out so far. When I initialize the different loggers like "node_logger" and "central_logger" in the main script, and then I retrieve them by logging.getLogger method works fine on the central entity but it completely fails on the clients level. Each client is (for some reason) returning to the basic logger that is set to 'warning' level.

Comment: The only method to make it work is to construct those functions (@staticmethods are used for different reasons here that stay beyond the scope of the problem) and then, during each client's initialisation, call client_logger = Loggers.client_logger(). I am trying to understand the root cause of this behaviour. It may be caused by the fact, that clients have methods that are sometimes executed in parallel - but still, the instance of the Logger object should be global. Once I get the logger with a particular name and configure it, I should be able to retrieve it by calling .getLogger(name).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your logger class as is here's how you could only initialise the logger once and have a child logger for each Client instance.

```
# Initialise logger
Loggers.client_logger()

class Client:
    def __init__():
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("node_logger").get_child(str(id(self)))
```